# Git error when I push and pull

Tags: git, github

I create a project and init git with following infos

```
git config user.name 'name'
git config user.email 'username@gmail.com'
```

and push the code to github, I use `git log`, and find the email address is wrong, so i update it with following

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "username@gmail.com" ];
then
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="the.username@gmail.com";
    git commit-tree "$@";
else
    git commit-tree "$@";
fi' -f HEAD
```

all commits are changed, and I push this to github again, but it fails with error

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

and ask me to pull, and i pull, but it show another error

```
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rewrote the repository history with filter-branch. When you push to github it notices that your changes would overwrite the old history. To prevent you from losing history by accident, it refuses to do so.

Usually this happens when someone else pushes new changes before you. Pushing the history with your changes would overwrite their changes. So the error message suggests that you merge their changes and then push the combined histories.

From https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/:
    git push origin master To https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git  ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git' To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

However in your case the advice does not apply. You do not want to merge your rewritten history with your old history. You really want to lose the old history. In this case, you can tell Git using git push --force origin master.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have rewritten your whole history with `filter-branch` command, and that history is different from what you have in GitHub. You can forcibly push your local commits with `git push -f`, it will override whatever you have in GitHub.